# Java Program Error: Cannot Find Symbol File

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, jfilechooser

I am writing a code in java to display text file in `JTextArea`. Can Anyone tell me what is wrong with this code. It is saying cannnot find symbol file..

```
FOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            final JFileChooser FileDialog = new JFileChooser();
            int ReturnValue=FileDialog.showOpenDialog(null);

            if(ReturnValue==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File file = FileDialog.getSelectedFile(); 
            }
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = in.readLine();    
            while(line!=null)
            {
                WritingArea.append(line+"\n");
                line=in.readLine();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Look up 'variable scope'.

Comment: Just put everything that's under the if statement, into the if statement, and you should be fine. You really do need to learn scopes though. The error tells you exactly whats wrong

Comment: When I declare the file above if 
File = file; 
I get an error that file not been initialized???

Comment: @BelalKhan - DO NOT edit the Question in a way that destroys its original meaning.  I'm reverting your bad edit.  If you have a follow-up Question either ask a new Question, or edit the existing Question to *add* the follow-up.  Do it *properly* please.

Answer (score 4):

Look up 'variable scope/visibility'.  Since the `file` attribute is *declared* inside the brackets, only code in that code block has access to it.

Other notes/tips:

- If `ReturnValue!= ..`  it does not make much sense to continue with the rest, so the rest of that method should also be inside the brackets.
- That code will bloc the EDT for as long as it takes to load the `File`.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.
- Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.
- if `WritingArea` is a `JTextComponent` there is an easier way to load the data.
- Always copy/paste error & exception output.
- For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You really need to learn about scopes.  Currently you File object is encapsulated in the if block's scope. If you want to use that File object anywhere else, it isn't allowed. So put everything into the if block, where they will be in the same scope as the File object

```
FOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        final JFileChooser FileDialog = new JFileChooser();
        int ReturnValue=FileDialog.showOpenDialog(null);

        if(ReturnValue==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = FileDialog.getSelectedFile(); 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = in.readLine(); 

            while(line!=null)
            {
                WritingArea.append(line+"\n");
                line=in.readLine();
            }
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: *"Am getting different error now"*  Then you should select an answer for this one, and *ask a new question!*  SO is not a help-desk, it is a Q&A Site..